# How to delete rows in r

Tags: r

So I've been trying to subset and remove the observations of a country from my data frame (ESS6). I have been able to remove certain variables with this function, -c(variable), but that is not useful since I only want to remove certain rows from the variable countries (cntry).

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `df <- df[-c(1, 2, 4), ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using dplyr and the "filter" function

Comment: `select` works on columns, not rows.